# EPSDK.Recordset not looping until EOF (end of file)

Tags: com, vb6, recordset

I am currently half way through a project where I am migrating data from an ancient Adobe Workflow server using Visual Basic and COM.

I have hit a bit of a brick wall really as I am trying to perform a simple while loop that counts the number of records in a recordset, and I keep getting this error...

*"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in microsoft.visualbasic.dll
Additional information: Unspecified error"*

There is little to no documentation to help me online so I am hoping there is some sort of VB wizard/veteran that can point me in the right direction.

I have set the record as a global variable like so...

```
Dim record As New EPSDK.Recordset
```

I have then tried...

```
Dim recCount As Integer = 0
Do Until record.EOF
        recCount += 1
    Loop
```

This...

```
Dim recCount As Integer = 0
Do While Not record.EOF
        recCount += 1
    Loop
```

This...

```
Dim recCount As Integer = 0
Do
        recCount += 1
    Loop Until record.EOF
```

And lots of other variations, but still cannot seem to source the problem. There are no code errors, nothing comes up in the console, and I just keep getting that message back.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: look up `MoveFirst()`

Comment: I have tried it and doesn't work. It fails on the while statement @vba4all

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've looked up the documentation for EPSDK.  For those who are unaware (as I was), it's an object collection from Adobe for manipulating COM data.  It's basically the most popular functionality in ADO.

MoveFirst, as its name suggests, moves to the first record in a recordset.  There doesn't appear to be any such method supported by the EPSDK Recordset object.  Since you can use the Move method to do the same thing, it isn't needed.  In either case, you don't need to use it to move to the end of the file.

What you're doing wrong is expecting that you can increment a variable called recCount that you made up and the recordset cursor will magically move along.  Doesn't happen.  As you say, the doc is insubstantial, but you probably need to use MoveNext.  [Here's](http://www.cnblogs.com/xuzhong/archive/2006/04/26/385052.html) a cheat sheet you can use to look up what's supported.

Also, you need to specify a connection, open it, point the recordset to the open connection, and open the recordset.  I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with ADO (NOT ADO.Net! Not the same thing), upon which this is clearly based.  There's much more documentation, and it should apply fairly well.  Read up on Connections and Recordsets in particular.

Now, your loops do pretty much the same thing.  While Not is the equivalent of Until.  However, if you put the while/until condition after the Do statement, you won't enter the loop unless the condition is met.  If you put it after the Loop statement, you will always run the loop at least once.  In this case, you should put "Do Until myRecordset.EOF", because then if the recordset is empty, you won't go into the loop.